# This requireJS thing has me confused

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i am trying to understand this steganography tool https://github.com/petereigenschink/steganography.js.

I am using this in my react project. The bit about **RequireJS** has me already confused. Can i turn this to a normal, not so scary javascript?

```
;(function (name, context, factory) {

  // Supports UMD. AMD, CommonJS/Node.js and browser context
  if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = factory();
  } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(factory);
  } else {
    context[name] = factory();
  }

  })("steg", this, function () {}
```

I need to be able to use this function or whatever it is in my App.js file. Any pointers please?

This is the error that react dev server throws:
    Failed to compile.

```
./src/steganography.js
  Line 12:  'define' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 13:   'define' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: this is normal. It is just an iife

Comment: this is perfectly normal javascript. I'd recommend understanding UMD and AMD

Comment: But this bit of snippet doesn't work in my react project. Can you show how this will be imported in another js file that is not using REQUIREJS.

Comment: What is your project using for module loading?

Comment: I used create-react-app to create the project. I am a beginner and use only the require('foo') or import foo from 'foo'.

Comment: I don't think this code is on npm, so here's what you do: Download the file, and put it somewhere in your codebase. Then when you want to use it, do `import steg from './path/to/the/file/steganography'`

Comment: I downloaded the file and used it in my project. I have added the error that is thrown.

Comment: That's just a lint error. ESLint is a tool for helping to enforce good coding practices. You shouldn't run lint on code that's outside your control. You can tell eslint to ignore files by adding them to your `.eslintignore` file. You may already have this file at the root level of your project, or you can create it if it doesn't exist. You can see more about configuring eslint here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#eslintignore

Comment: I added a `.eslintignore` file with **/src/steganography.js** inside it. Compilation still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript didn't originally include any way of doing modules (ie, to link together code from multiple files), several different approaches have been invented for ways to do so. That block of code is just trying to conform to all of them, so that the codebase will work regardless of which module approach the consumer is using.

The outer part is an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). This is an anonymous function which gets created and then immediately called. In this code, its main purpose is to isolate any variables inside the expression, and thus make it impossible for them to accidentally become global variables.

Inside the IIFE, it has some checks to figure out what kind of module system is being used, so that it can produce the correct output to be imported.